# Can't install linux-image-extra-3.16.0-50-generic

Tags: apt, purge

So I tried to do `sudo apt-get purge samba`

It gives me

```
kevin@Server:~$ sudo apt-get purge samba
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-50-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-50-generic bu                                                                                                             t it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic-lts-utopic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-50-generic but it                                                                                                              is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a s                                                                                                             olution).
```

So I decide to do`apt-get -f install` 
I also do `apt-get install linux-image-3.16.0-50-generic`

both of them result in error and here is the error message:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-3.16.0-50-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-50-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-50-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic-lts-utopic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-50-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

**EDIT**

If I do `sudo apt-get -f install` I will get the following

```
Unpacking linux-image-3.16.0-50-generic (3.16.0-50.67~14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-50-generic_3.16.0-50.67~14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-50-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-50-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-50-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-50-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-50-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-50-generic
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-50-generic_3.16.0-50.67~14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

what should I do?? I am completely lost....

Comment: You did `sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-3.16.0-50-generic`. Take out the `-extra` part and try again.

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: And do you just use the terminal or maybe you could use synaptic, it's much easier.

Comment: @Raphael I am using 14.04 server

Comment: @Zacharee1 It will result in `Unable to locate package`

Comment: Note this in your error message: "No space left on device". Your partition is full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set a separated boot partition?

it seems you have a disk full error, isn't it?

> cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-50-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-50-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
>   No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error

have you tried?:
`sudo apt-get autoremove`

it will remove your old kernel images from /boot
I think it's the sollution

Comment: That does it!!! my boot partition was 100%.